# How do I increase FOV above 90?

Tags: scrap-mechanic

The in-game settings only lets you put the FOV at 90. Is there any way to increase this by editing the files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually edit the `settings.json` file to do this.

- Navigate to the following directory:

  `C:\Users\<your_user>\AppData\Roaming\Axolot Games\Scrap Mechanic\User\User_XXXXXXXXXXX`
- Open `settings.json` with your preferred text editor (I use Notepad++)
- Change the value next to `"FOV"`

If you have an FOV of 90, this number will be 9. You must divide your desired FOV by 10 and use that value.

For example, if I want an FOV of 110, I would change it to 11.